# Netbeans 8 JSF 2 unrecognized tags

Tags: netbeans, browser

This is really a very basic problem. I have a web project working on a PC, with Netbeans 8 and JSF 2, and when I open the same sources on another PC, the jsf tags are not processed. I have made sure that the project uses the JSF framework. I tried to run it against Chrome, Firefox and IE, but the page displays only the html content.
What am I missing?

Comment: Did you ensure the other pc contsins the necessary .jar files?

Comment: Yes you are correct, at the time I did not know which jar where missing. Many thanks